# CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder not giving expected result

Tags: java, hibernate, criteriaquery, criteriabuilder

I'm using CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder to mount a dynamic where. I have some filtering values that user selects and can be informed or not. But using a conjunction predicate doesn't return a correct where clause.
This is my code:

```
// Create CriteriaBuilder
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
// Create CriteriaQuery
CriteriaQuery<Tarea> criteria = builder.createQuery(Tarea.class);
// Set root
Root<Tarea> root = criteria.from(Tarea.class);
criteria.select(root);
if(getSortColumn()!= null && !getSortColumn().equals("")) {
    criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get(getSortColumn())));
}
Predicate predFinal = builder.conjunction();
if(filtro.getClasificacionTarea() != null && filtro.getClasificacionTarea().size()>0) {
    Predicate predClasificacion = builder.disjunction();
    for(Clasificacion clas : filtro.getClasificacionTarea()) {
        predClasificacion.getExpressions().add(builder.equal(root.get("clasificacion").get("id"), clas.getId()));
    }
    predFinal.getExpressions().add(predClasificacion);
}
if(filtro.getProyecto() != null) {
    Predicate predicateProyecto;
    predicateProyecto = builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("OT").get("proyecto"), filtro.getProyecto()));
    predFinal.getExpressions().add(predicateProyecto);
}
if(filtro.getCliente() != null) {
    Predicate predicateCliente;
    predicateCliente = builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("ot").get("cliente").get("id"), filtro.getCliente().getId()));
    predFinal.getExpressions().add(predicateCliente);
}
if(filtro.getProvincia() != null) {
    Predicate predicateProvincia;
    predicateProvincia = builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("ot").get("provincia").get("id"), filtro.getProvincia().getId()));
    predFinal.getExpressions().add(predicateProvincia);
}
if(filtro.getPais() != null) {
    Predicate predicatePais;
    predicatePais = builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("ot").get("pais").get("id"), filtro.getPais().getId()));
    predFinal.getExpressions().add(predicatePais);
}
predFinal.getExpressions().add(builder.and(builder.isNull(root.get("fechaBaja"))));
criteria.where(predFinal);
// Query execution
Query<Tarea> query = session.createQuery(criteria);
```

And the resulting query, when filtering by any of the fields:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        t1_0.id,
        t1_0.fk_idPedidoVenta,
        t1_0.fk_idClasificacionTarea,
        t1_0.confirmado,
        t1_0.fk_idUsuarioCreacion,
        t1_0.fechaCreacion,
        t1_0.fechaBaja,
        t1_0.fechaInicio,
        t1_0.fechaFin,
        t1_0.finalizado,
        t1_0.horaInicio,
        t1_0.horaFin,
        t1_0.observaciones,
        t1_0.fk_idTipoTarea 
    from
        Tarea t1_0 
    where
        1=1 
    order by
        t1_0.fechaInicio
```

Where clause is always 1=1 so it returns all records.

It's my first time using CriteriaBuilder so maybe I'm using it wrong?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because you use `Predicate.getExpressions` to gather the predicates. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Predicate.html#getExpressions--), adding predicates directly to this list does not affect the query, i.e., the method most likely returns a defensive copy of the list of predicates. To fix it, I would create a list of `Predicate`s manually:

```java
final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
```

add the individual predicates to it (based on the `if` conditions) and then use the `CriteriaBuilder.and` to get a conjunction:

```java
criteria.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
```

Comment: `and` is not needed when used directly with `where`, you can just use `where(predicates.toArray(...))`. I also prefer `Predicate[]::new` over `new Predicate[0]` these days, because it removes the need to use reflection inside `toArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the expressions of a `Predicate`. From [Predicate.getExpressions()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/persistence/criteria/predicate#getExpressions--) (emphasis added):

> Return the top-level conjuncts or disjuncts of the predicate. Returns empty list if there are no top-level conjuncts or disjuncts of the predicate. **Modifications to the list do not affect the query.**

It seems like [conjuction()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/persistence/criteria/criteriabuilder#conjunction--) is not the way to go:

> Create a conjunction (with zero conjuncts). A conjunction with zero conjuncts is true.

So instead of using `conjuction()`, create a `List<Predicate>`, add to that, and then use it:

```
criteria.where(predicateList.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
```

Alternatively, and I think this is why `conjuction()` exists, don't add to its expressions but replace the predicate itself:

```
// predFinal.getExpressions().add(predClasificacion);
predFinal = builder.and(predFinal, predClasificacion);
```